# Gatsby WordPress - Graphql Paginate Categories

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

Is there any way that I can have one query and gatsby-paginate creates all pagination for all category?

Instead of doing it like this, which where I have to create the query manually for each category.

gatsby-node.js

```
graphql(queryCatUncategorized).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
        console.log(result.errors)
        reject(result.errors)
    }
    createPaginatedPages({
        edges: result.data.allWordpressPost.edges,
        createPage: createPage,
        pageTemplate: "src/templates/category.js",
        pageLength: 2,
        pathPrefix: "uncategorized",
    })
    // END Paginate Categories - Uncategorized
})
```

Is there anyway that I can do it like this?

```
.then(() => {
    return graphql(`
      {
        allWordpressCategory(filter: { count: { gt: 0 } }) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
              slug
            }
          }
        }
allWordpressPost(filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: "uncategorized"}}}}) {
          edges {
          node {
            id
            slug
            title
            categories {
              name
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
      }
    `)
})
    .then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            result.errors.forEach(e => console.error(e.toString()))
            return Promise.reject(result.errors)
        }

        const categoriesTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/category.js`)

        // Create a Gatsby page for each WordPress Category
        _.each(result.data.allWordpressCategory.edges, ({ node: cat }) => {
            createPaginatedPages({
                edges: result.data.allWordpressPost.edges,
                createPage: createPage,
                pageTemplate: categoriesTemplate,
                pageLength: 2,
                pathPrefix: `/category/${cat.slug}`
            })
        })
    })
```

The problem with this is that,

This only returns the posts under **uncategorized** category.

```
allWordpressPost(filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: "uncategorized"}}}}) {
```

Removing the filter will show all posts.

```
allWordpressPost {
```

This doesn't work

```
allWordpressPost(filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: "$slug"}}}}) {
```

I just started learning Gatsby few days ago and I'm a complete noob with JavaScript & React so please go easy on me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59423365/6124657 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly with GraphQL without inferring the schema and adapting it to your needs. One easy thing you can do, outside the box of GraphQL is to use JavaScript to filter and create a valid object to be used along with `createPaginatedPages`.

You have listed all the categories in `allWordpressCategory.edges.node.slug` so:

```
let allCategories=[];

allWordpressPost.edges.map(post=> {
    post.category && allCategories.push(post.category);

    return new Set (allCategories);
});
```

Basically, looping through all posts and populating the array of categories (`allCategories`), and returning a `new Set` (to avoid duplicated results) will create a valid array of categories, that you can loop to create your category pages.

> This doesn't work
>
> ```
> allWordpressPost(filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: "$slug"}}}}) {}
> ```

As I said, the only way without changing the GraphQL schema, to pass data to your GraphQL queries is to use the [context](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/programmatically-create-pages-from-data/), but not nesting queries. Using the context will allow you to pass data to your template query, but in this case, since you need the data before creating pages, it won't work for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks Ferran, I'll give this a try. 
/me still learning xD`